# Record deletion

Tags: oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have below table 'tbl_main' with around 8K records

```
Id   Name  ExId
1    AB    X0001
3    FD    X000-01
.    .     ...
.    .     ....
```

And I have a `text file` with data(4K records), each row separated by newline  like below:

```
ExID
X000-01
X7654
AD7778
..
..
..
```

I need to delete data from 'tbl_main' where tbl_main's ExId are not matched with ExId of the text file.

```
delete from tbl_main where ExId not in('X000-01','X7654','AD7778',.....4K)
```

Due to limitation of `IN` clause I cannot do it right?
Also I don't want to put text file's data in `temp` table to server the deletion, unless don't have any other way.

So, How can I achieve this. Please advice.

I am using Oracle Sql Developer and Oracle 10g.

Comment: Iterate through the textual file with chunks of IDs which number is allowed to be placed in the `in` statement.

Comment: that way I will loose data

Comment: You could create an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) on the file.

Comment: Or use [UTL_FILE package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF) to open and read the file, and perform a delete statement for each line read.

Comment: @TonyAndrews: I want to delete unmatched records not matched one. so performing delete by reading each line will not happen.
Say, i have x001, x002 in tbl_main and x002 in text file. After deletion task completed I should have x002 record in tbl_main.

Comment: OK I see.  So you need to know all the IDs from the file at once.  So the external table method would work for you. Or you can read all the values into a table type and use `where exid not in (select column_value from table(v_table))`